# How do I adapt data from an array of objects so that it can be summed?

Tags: arrays, matlab, object

I have a `channel` object that contains an array of `filterL` objects. Each `filterL` object has some data `H`. Typing the following into the console . . .

```
channel.filterL(:).H
```

gives the output . . .

```
ans =

   0.0140 - 0.0414i
   0.0133 - 0.0181i
   0.0131 - 0.0095i
   0.0131 - 0.0042i
   0.0131 - 0.0000i


ans =

   0.0140 - 0.0416i
   0.0133 - 0.0181i
   0.0131 - 0.0095i
   0.0131 - 0.0042i
   0.0131 - 0.0000i


ans =

   0.0140 - 0.0420i
   0.0133 - 0.0181i
   0.0131 - 0.0095i
   0.0131 - 0.0042i
   0.0131 - 0.0000i
```

I cannot simply sum this output like so . . .

```
>> sum(channel.filterL(:).H)
??? Error using ==> sum
Too many input arguments.
```

So my question is how do I efficiently reorganise my data so that it can be summed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concatenate your data first to change it into one array

```
[channel.filterL(:).H]
```

Comment: I knew it had to be simple, but I didn't realise it was that simple! I will accept as soon as it lets me!